# Where to do user authentication in webapp?

Tags: java, web-applications, spring-mvc

In a Spring MVC web application where every page except for Home, About, Terms of Service, etc. can be viewed only if the user is logged in, where is the best place to do authentication? At the filter level, controller level, or both?

I'm asking this because now that I'm writing my Controllers, I've been repeating a lot of code like:

```
if (currentUser.isAuthenticated()) // and possibly currentUser.hasPermission("some")
    // do logic and return proper page
else 
    // return to home or login page
```

Would it be better to put all the pages that require authentication under some url pattern and protect (catch and redirect if user not authenticated) them with a filter? This way the controller is cleaner and simply returns the page requested.

What's proper design in this case?

Comment: Generally speaking, the higher up front the authentication is, the better. As this is a webapp, can't you inject the "logged in/not logged in" at the web.xml level? I don't use Spring, therefore I don't know how it works in this case...

Comment: I believe you can do that (I don't know how though), but I want to have more programmatic control over it, like log the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow [the outline given in the Spring Security reference guide](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/technical-overview.html#tech-intro-web-authentication), even if you don't use that project itself. It's good advice on how to implement security in a webapp.

Answer (score 1):

You need an interceptor. I had a similar question regarding this a few years back regarding authentication and session handling [[Spring MVC 3 Global Request Mapping]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7216474/spring-mvc-3-global-request-mapping). Here is how I solved and implemented it  [[Github source for authentication session handling using interceptor]](https://github.com/QuynhNguyen/Qake-Java-EE/blob/master/src/interceptor/GlobalInterceptor.java).

Comment: The interceptor seems good, but I don't like the way you did it. I don't want to store the user's password in the cookie and I don't want to have html in anything that isn't a view, because I have different return styles, json, xml, or jsps.

Comment: The password is encrypted in the cookie, and that is how you usually deal with cookie authentication. As for my html in postHandler, it is a way I used to handle global html but I am sure you can refractor and make it look better.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to secure spring applications with spring security.
you config your security in xml and it creates servlet filter for your application.